# Can't remove preference headers from my app

Tags: android

In an attempt to make my app compatible with Gingerbread devices, I have consulted and used the following resources:

https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Prefs/FragmentsBC
http://actionbarsherlock.com/

Somewhere in the process of attempting to make my app compatible, this started happening: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kusNw.png

So instead of my Main Activity opening directly, it opens the header first, and I have to click that to go to what should open in the first place.

I believe it started when I copied code over from the FragmentsBC example listed above.  But after deleting all references to "headers" and any xml files associated with it, it still shows up.  I have searched for the word "header" throughout my entire app project, and there is not one reference to it found anywhere.  Yet I can't figure out why it is still showing up.

All help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So instead of my Main Activity opening directly, it opens the header first, and I have to click that to go to what should open in the first place.

That's how the `FragmentsBC` sample is supposed to work.

> Yet I can't figure out why it is still showing up.

[The `SingleHeader` sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Prefs/SingleHeader) shows using some methods on `PreferenceActivity` to determine if we are in dual-pane mode, and to skip the headers in that case.

[The `SingleHeader2` sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Prefs/SingleHeader2) shows using some semi-documented extras to tell `PreferenceActivity` to skip the headers and jump straight to a specific `PreferenceFragment`.

Comment: CommonsWare, what a treat that you are the one to help me.  Thank you.  1.) What is dual-pane mode? 2.) I understand the sample apps are supposed to use the headers, but they are now showing up in my actual app, even though I have deleted the preference_headers file and removed any references to it.  So I am still not understanding why it is showing up.

Comment: @Richard: "What is dual-pane mode?" -- the side-by-side presentation of headers and preference fragments, as seen on tablets in landscape. "So I am still not understanding why it is showing up" -- beats me. Are you sure that you are running your modified app?

Comment: yup, I'm subscribing to your book.  Both in support for all the free help you give, and also for the 2,400+ pages of pure Android goodness.  Turns out I was not running my modified app.  I accidentally had the "Is Library" checkbox checked in the Android properties of my project.  So somehow it was running the version I had right before I did that.  Thank you so much.

Comment: @Richard: Glad it is working for you, and thanks for the kind words!